# Retrieve & hold call in twilio

Tags: twilio

I put the twilio call on hold by following snippet

```
var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(Settings.AccountSid, Settings.AuthToken);
        twilio.RedirectCall(callSid, Settings.HoldMusic, "GET");
```

But i want to retrieve the holded call back.. Can you please any one help me with code snippet

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like what you'd like to achieve is tracking the status of a call that is on hold as described in this [FAQ](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/voice/how-do-i-track-the-call-status-of-an-outbound-call).

You can use the [`StatusCallbackEvent` parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#post-parameters-optional) on outbound calls made via the REST API. If you're indeed using the [C# helper library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/csharp) it would look something like this:

```
var options = new CallOptions();
options.Url = "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml";
options.From = "+18668675309";
options.Method = "GET";
options.StatusCallback = "https://www.myapp.com/events";
options.StatusCallbackMethod = "POST";
options.StatusCallbackEvents = new string[] { "initiated", "ringing", "answered", "completed" };
```

Also, depending on your use case, there is now a dedicated [`Hold` feature](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/participant) available when using `<Conference>` as detailed in [this post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/06/introducing-conference-hold.html).